# dplyr mutate to replace specific values in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that consists of characters "a", "b", "x", "y".

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "b", "x", "y"),
                 v2 = c("a", "b", "a", "y"))
```

Now I want to replace all values with the following scheme and also convert the whole data frame to numeric.

"a" -> 0
"b" -> 1
"x" -> 1
"y" -> 2

I know this must be somehow possible with `mutate_all` but I cannot figure out how

```
df %>% mutate_all(replace("a", 1)) %>%
       mutate_all(is.character, as.numeric)
```

Comment: maybe car::recode could be helpful here? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-2/topics/recode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be with `case_when`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(case_when(. == "a" ~ 0, 
                            . %in% c("b", "x") ~ 1, 
                            . == "y" ~ 2, 
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_)))

#   v1 v2
# 1  0  0
# 2  1  1
# 3  1  0
# 4  2  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a named vector with mappings and then subset it using `mutate_all`

```
vec <- c(a = 0, b = 1, x = 1, y = 2)

library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(~vec[.])

#  v1 v2
#1  0  0
#2  1  1
#3  1  0
#4  2  2
```

---

In base R that would be just

```
df[] <- vec[unlist(df)]
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "b", "x", "y"),
                 v2 = c("a", "b", "a", "y"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```